# What is this concept called?

Tags: php, oop

What is this concept called in programming?  Particularly the bit in the constructor.  I'd like to have a term to google.

```
<?PHP
class Foo{
    private $bar;

    function __construct(){
        **$a = new Foo();
        $a->setBar("Do I ever get printed?");
        $this = $a;**
    }

    function setBar($a){ 
        $this->bar = $a; 
    } 

    function getBar(){
        return $this->bar
    }
}
?>

<?PHP

$z = new Foo();
echo $z->getBar();

?>
```

Comment: Haha.  I guess I should have thought that one through a bit more.  I was trying to come up with a use for the craziness that came out of my mind and the first thing to come to mind would be creating objects that follow a pattern that can be described recursively.  For instance: (x,y) coordinates that describe a Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Infinite recursion".